# An opposite method of padding argument on N/DTIME complexity class

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes

Is there a method to prove things with longer input in complexity theory?

For example, using padding argument it's trivial to show that
$\text{NTIME}(n^2) \subseteq \text{DTIME}(n^4) \Rightarrow \forall k \ge 2, \text{NTIME}(n^k) \subseteq \text{DTIME}(n^{2k})$

Is there a common method for the opposite direction, i.e., for something like
$\text{NTIME}(n^4) \subseteq \text{DTIME}(n^{12}) \Rightarrow \forall 1 \ge k < 4, \text{NTIME}(n^k) \Rightarrow \text{DTIME}(n^{3k})$?